# puppeteer input fields are not taken into account

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I’m using puppeteer to login to a website:

```
await page.$eval('input[name="email"]', el => el.value = 'my_email');
await page.$eval('input[name="password"]', (el, my_value) => {el.value = my_value}, my_password);
await page.click('button[type="submit"]');
```

The email and password are typed in correctly, but when the script clicks on the button "Submit", it’s as if nothing had been typed in the "email" and "password" fields (I get an error message "This field is required." for both).

So the website thinks the input fields are still empty. What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you try using the `type` function instead?

Comment: @hardkoded type is working, and I don’t remember why I used $eval in the past. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page must be doing something on some input event, like `keypress`. You could use `type` instead. That will simulate a user input.

```js
await page.type('input[name="email"]', 'my_email');
await page.type('input[name="password"]', my_password);
await page.click('button[type="submit"]');
```